# No payment methods listed in the SagePay(Test mode) page that the user is redirected for payment

Tags: opayo

I am trying out a sample Sage Pay integration ASP.Net MVC application provided by
Jeremy Skinner (https://github.com/JeremySkinner/SagePayMvc).

On checking out my shopping cart, I am successfully redirected to the Sage Pay payment page. But no payment methods are listed on the page. The following payment methods have been added by the administrator.

1. Visa
2. Master Card
3. Maestro

I have no idea what could be causing the issue. Please note that
Sage Pay is in 'Test' mode

Thanks in advance

Mathew